# Can you list a Datastore Cluster's sDRS Schedule via PowerCLI?

Tags: cluster, vmware-vcenter, datastore, powercli

We have a lot of datastore clusters, most if not all are supposed to have sDRS schedules applied to stop them moving VMs at busy periods.

Obviously we could trawl through them manually to check if they're how they should be but I like to do things like this via PowerCLI if possible.

I've tried what I can and can't seem to find a command-string to dump this information - does anyone know if it's possible please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sDRS schedules are regular vCenter scheduled tasks. There are few blog posts available on how to list these with PowerCLI, e.g. here:

https://virtualbyte.wordpress.com/2014/09/05/retrieve-vcenter-scheduled-task-with-powercli/
http://rvdnieuwendijk.com/2013/01/19/get-vmware-vcenter-scheduled-tasks-with-powercli/

I personally like this one liner from the first blog post:

```
(Get-View ScheduledTaskManager).ScheduledTask | %{ (Get-View $_).Info }
```

... but to get to the details of the sDRS settings changed by the task it's a long way down the properties of the returned object.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, I'd not been in a position to test it until now but that's perfect - I'd gotten myself so tied up wondering why it wasn't a function of sDRS that I'd blinded myself to the fact it was setup as a normal scheduled task - thanks again.